# Inserting array values into a html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I got an array that holds info that is being queried from two game servers. It looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [PERP] => Array ( 
        [gq_address] => 192.168.1.1 
        [gq_dedicated] => d 
        [gq_gametype] => 
        [gq_hostname] => Test Server 1
        [gq_mapname] => gm_construct 
        [gq_maxplayers] => 60 
        [gq_mod] => garrysmod 
        [gq_numplayers] => 11 
        [gq_online] => 1 
        [gq_password] => 0 
        [gq_port] => 27016 
        [gq_protocol] => source 
        [gq_transport] => udp 
        [gq_type] => gmod
    )

    [TTT] => Array ( 
        [gq_address] => 192.168.1.1
        [gq_dedicated] => d 
        [gq_gametype] => 
        [gq_hostname] => Test Server 2
        [gq_mapname] => gm_construct 
        [gq_maxplayers] => 30 
        [gq_mod] => garrysmod 
        [gq_numplayers] => 0 
        [gq_online] => 1 
        [gq_password] => 0 
        [gq_port] => 27029 
        [gq_protocol] => source 
        [gq_transport] => udp 
        [gq_type] => gmod  
    ) 
)
```

And then I have a table that shows the information in the array. However, currently it's showing both servers on the same row in the table. The table looks like this:

```
<?php
echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';
echo '<tr>';

foreach($results as $perp) { 
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_type'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_online'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_hostname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_address'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_port'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_numplayers'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_mapname'] . '</td>';
}

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

So currently it's printing both the "Test Server 1" and "Test Server 2" on the same row in the table. How do I make a table that separates the two arrays on one row each?

Here you can see the table : http://zfrag.se/servers.php

Comment: Put the `<tr>` and `</tr>` in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
echo '<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">';

foreach($results as $perp) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_type'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_online'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_hostname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_address'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_port'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_numplayers'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $perp['gq_mapname'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: You should output this to an image, then it can be used a signature. Very cool.